# While editing in ckeditor application is considered as ideal and so logged out when session expires

Tags: ckeditor

I am working with ckeditor. While editing anything in the editor, application is considered as ideal (like no activity) and so when session expires it is logging out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "StateServer" mode which uses an external process (service) to store the session. It will survive a recycling of the worker process.

More about StateServer Mode

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1420/stateserver-session-state-in-asp-dot-net